# My query is right in PhpMyAdmin, wrong while called by my website

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This same exact query is giving me an error while calling it from my website, but if I copy and paste it into PhpMyAdmin sql editor, it is fine. It says that there is a syntax error near select rank, score...

```php
     $dbResult = mysql_query
    ('
        set @rank=0;
        select rank, score from
            ( select @rank:=@rank+1 as rank, id, score
             from leaderboard 
             group by id
             order by score desc ) as rank_found 
        where id=10';
    ');
```

Comment: that's not **one** query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the set of statements used, you have to use [`'multi_query'`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) in php.

Alternatively you can modify your query as follows:

```
select rank, score 
  from ( 
         select @rank:=@rank+1 as rank, id, score
           from leaderboard
              , ( select @rank := 0 ) as initializer 
          group by id
          order by score desc 
  ) as rank_found 
where id=10;
```

And you better go with `mysqli_*` as `mysql_*` usage is deprecated.

Comment: Just a note that `multi_query` is part of `MySQLi` and not the outdated `MySQL` library that appears to be in use for the OP. ^^